# Change language depending on the dropdown select in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, locale

I am using i18n and depending on the selection from the dropdown I would like to change the language of the application here is the code snipped what is missing?

```
i18n.configure({
  locales: ['eng', 'rus'],
  defaultLocale: 'rus',
  directory: __dirname + '/static/locales',
  cookiename: 'locale'
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.__ = res.__ = function() {
      console.log(i18n.__.apply(req, arguments));
        return i18n.__.apply(req, arguments);
    };
    next();
});

app.get('/:locale', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
    i18n.setLocale(i18n, req.params.locale);
    res.redirect(req.headers.referer);
});
```